# Java String UTF-8 limits

Tags: java, string, utf-8, limits

I'm trying to deserialize Strings from files directly and I have a question about very long Strings: Java Strings have a character count limit equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is 31^2-1.

But here comes my question: what happens when I have a UTF-8 String with little less than that size but formed by characters with size more than 1 byte and then I ask Java to give me the byte array?

To make it clearer, what happens if I could run this code? (I haven't got RAM enough):

```
String toPrint = "";
String string100 = "";
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE -100;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
    string100 += "1234567ñ90";
}
for (int i = 0; i < max; i += 100) {
    toPrint += string100;
}
System.out.println("String complete!");
byte[] byteArray = toPrint.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(byteArray.length);
System.exit(0);
```

Does it print "String complete!"? Or does it break before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, the limit on `Strings` is that the `char` arrays inside of them can't be longer than the maximum array length, which is roughly `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and greater than your variable `max`. Strings store their characters in UTF-16 and therefore the UTF-16 representation of a string can't exceed the maximum array length. The number of bytes in UTF-8 and the number of logical characters (Unicode code points, or UTF-32 characters) ultimately don't matter.

Now let's move to your particular example. Since each of the 10 characters in "1234567ñ90" is a single UTF-16 value, that string takes up 10 values of a `String`'s `char` array. Despite your code's horrible performance and high memory requirement, it should eventually get to "String complete!" if there is sufficient available memory. However, it will break when converting to UTF-8 because the UTF-8 representation of the string is longer than the maximum array length, since "ñ" requires more than one byte.

Comment: I agree with the horrible performance, it's just a proof of concept XD

Comment: But then, how can Java serialize and deserialize it? Because Java uses an UTF-8 array to serialize...

Comment: @nicovell3 If string serialization calls `String.getBytes(UTF-8)`, it will fail. If it doesn't fail, it's using another way to convert to UTF-8.

Comment: It does not use it and now I understand why. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Array size is also limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is why `String` size is limited, after all there's a `char[]` backing it) , so it's impossible to get the byte array if the encoding uses more bytes than that, no matter what the size of the `String` is in characters.

The end result would be an `OutOfMemoryError`, but creating the `String` in the first place would succeed.